# In Flash page Select box (combobox) is not working using Webdriver

Tags: java, webdriver, watir-webdriver

I have done some sample code to select a combobox using webdriver in a Flash page but Select(...) and type(....) methods are not working but click(....) method works fine.

Please help to resolve this.
Type-1: Below methods are not working.

```
public void type(String locator, String value)
{
    ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("document.getElementById('" + flashObjectId + "').fp_type({" + locator +", 'text':'"+ value +"'})");
}

public void select(String locator, String value) 
{
    ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("document.getElementById('" + flashObjectId + "').fp_select({" + locator +", 'label':'"+ value +"'})");
}
```

Its working fine in below click(....) method.

```
public String click(final String objectId, final String optionalButtonLabel) 
{
    return call("doFlexClick", objectId, optionalButtonLabel);
}

private String call(final String functionName, final String... args) 
{
    final Object result =
          ((JavascriptExecutor)webDriver).executeScript(
               makeJsFunction(functionName, args),
               new Object[0]);

       return result != null ? result.toString() : null;
}


private String makeJsFunction(final String functionName, final String... args) 
{
    final StringBuffer functionArgs = new StringBuffer();

    if (args.length > 0) 
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) 
        {
           if (i > 0) 
            {
               functionArgs.append(",");
            }
           functionArgs.append(String.format("'%1$s'", args[i]));
           System.out.println("functionArgs: "+functionArgs);
          }
     }

     return String.format(
       "return document.%1$s.%2$s(%3$s);",
       flashObjectId,
       functionName,
       functionArgs);
}
```

Please help to fix this in select box and tyep operation using webdriver in Flash.

Thanks in Advance,
Gopal

Answer (score 1):

Watir-Webdriver does not support flash pages.

Comment: Thank you SCott for your support.                                                                    I have gone through URL :                                               http://selenium-tips.blogspot.in/p/webdriver-and-flex-pilot-together-as.html                                                                      and done same changes in my local click(...) method works fine, but not Select box(combo box), Type, DragandDrop operations.